# Rails: how to set json format for redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, redirect, routes

How I can redirect not to html format but to json?

I want smthing like this:

```
redirect_to user_path(@user), format: :json
```

But this doesn't work, I still redirected to html path.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I read apidock some more... It was quite simple. I just should specify format in path helper like this:

```
redirect_to user_path(@user, format: :json)
```

Comment: If this is done within a format.js request the response does not actually redirect the page though, it just sends the html to the browser async. Is this the only way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629811/rails-redirect-to-format-html-sends-response-in-js

Comment: @ajbraus JS is not JSON. The question/answer you linked is dealing with requests where the format specified is actually javascript that will be executed, not for situations where you are responding to an API request (potentially not even coming from a client that supports JavaScript, like an iOS app).

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer (specifying `format: :json` in the `redirect_to` options) wasn't working for me in a Rails 5.2 API app; requests with an `Accept: application/json` header.

Using `redirect_to "/foo", format: :json` resulted in a response like this (edited for brevity):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /foo

<html><body>You are being <a href="/foo">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

This does not work for an API, so instead of using `redirect_to` at all I switched to using [head](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Head.html#method-i-head):

```
head :found, location: "/foo"
```

This results in the following response (again, edited for brevity) without a body, which is precisely what I was looking for:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: application/json
Location: /foo
```

In my case I wasn't redirecting to a page in my Rails app, so I didn't use a URL helper, but if you are doing so (e.g. `user_path` or `redirect_to @user`) you can provide the relevant option to your URL helper like so:

```
head :found, location: user_path(user, format: :json)
# or
head :found, location: url_for(@user, format: :json)
```

Comment: If you specify 302 or any other 3xx than 304, the user agent might automatically redirect to a given Location header.

In my case, I was sending 304 with the Location header from API to redirect the user to a different page by checking this data in the front-end.