# rails redirect_to format html sends response in js

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, redirect

I made a before_filter in some of my controller to redirect keyword searches to the parent controller

It's very simple:

```
  before_filter :redirect_search
  def redirect_search
    redirect_to controller: "buildings", action: "index", format: "html" if params[:q].present?
  end
```

Please note that the keyword_search is sent in "js" format

Everything seems to work. When I look at the server, I can see that the buildings/index is run and that the page is rendered but nothing happens in the browser.

In the browser's console I see this

```
GET http://localhost:3000/buildings.html 200 OK
```

It has the html page in the response body

This means that buildings/index is run as html but then sent as js to the browser.

Why is that so? How can I fix it?

Comment: can you try adding a return at the end of redirect_search ?

Comment: You mean you are using AJAX to go to keyword searches and there you are redirecting it to another url.html ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to Bachan's answer, I could solve my issue this way:

```
  def redirect_search
    render :js => "window.location.href='"+buildings_path+"'" if params[:q].present?
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wow is that ugly. Is there something missing here in Rails, or are we not doing things the Rails way to begin with?

Comment: I actually needed that and this is the only way I could make it work, in 2021 with Rails 6. If anyone knows something better nowadays please comment!

Answer (score 18):

Try with

```
def redirect_search
     respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to buildings_path} if params[:q].present?
            format.js {render :js => "window.location.href='"+buildings_path+"'"} if params[:q].present?
     end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the view which is doing the request

you are sending a JS request (ajax), so you should return a js.erb file and render new HTML using js