# Rails redirect renders HTML, but browser doesn't display it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'm having an odd issue redirecting and rendering in my Rails 3.2 app.

From my create controller action, I've got the following respond_to block

```
// request type here is JSON
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { redirect_to( v2_promote_path(@challenge), content_type: "text/html") }
end
```

...which redirects to the following action in the same controller:

```
def promote
  // request type is JSON here
  request.format = :html
  @challenge = Challenge.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { render '/challenges/v2/promote_challenge.html.erb'}
  end
end
```

The odd part is that this renders the promote_challenge template in the HTTP response, but the browser doesn't display it.

The redirect action gets a request type of application/json, even though I explicitly set it to HTML in the redirect call, the HTML still only gets rendered in the response, not the browser.

Question: why am I getting the HTML in the response, but not in the browser?

Here are the request/response headers:

```
REQUEST:
GET /v2/challenges/18236/promote HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
X-XSRF-TOKEN: asldfkasldkfas=
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/v2/challenges/preview

RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using `format` instead?

```
redirect_to( v2_promote_path(@challenge), format: :html)
```

Comment: Tried it but got the exact same behavior. Thanks though

Comment: I think there's a limitation / assumption here with Rails that is preventing you from doing this using the normal conventions.  This post should outline a hacky way (see accepted answer) to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629811/rails-redirect-to-format-html-sends-response-in-js.  BUT, I think you probably want to render your html in a js template instead and have the client replace the contents (see last answer)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted hacky solution is pretty ugly; we can agree with that.It's just having rails tell the client to execute Javascript that will do the redirect.

A more clean solution, in my opinion, is to handle the redirect in your success callback in JS:

`render :json => { status: 'success' }` in rails 
then do something like

```
success: function(data) {
   // Send user to next page.
   window.location.href = "http://www.myawesomesite.com/page";
},
```

in JS.