# Browser doesn't display HTML content after redirect response

Tags: javascript, http, redirect

I am developing a web app in `java` (using `vert.x`).
I have a login screen where I want to redirect the user after a successful login. The request is of type `POST`, and the response is `302`.

In the network section under chrome dev tools, I can see the redirect response and the following request which returns the html, but the browser doesn't display it.

I have seen a few posts about it ([rails example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629811/rails-redirect-to-format-html-sends-response-in-js), bu they all offered a hacky solution, changing the location of the html.

Is there a better way to achieve this using the "native" HTTP response types?

Comment: _which returns the html, but the browser doesn't display it_ - can you show a screen shot with response body that is made after `302` response. what framework do you use on client?

Comment: For the simplicity of the page, just native js, no framework. I can't display a screen shot though because the web app is on a different network. The redirect (302) body is empty, the following response (GET request) returns the appropriate HTML page

Comment: and no error is shown? this shouldn't happen, if your GET response contains valid HTML, the browser will show it. what's the location  header value? does the browser update location path in a browser?

Comment: No it does not. The location header changes accordingly to the requested page. For example, it can contain '/some/resource', but in order to view the page, the user need to login first. So I send him the login page, then the user execute a POST request, and recieve 302 redirect which results in another 200 response with the HTML content

Comment: _and recieve 302 redirect_ - what's the location header here? do you have any environment to observe this behavior?

Comment: I'm working on my localhost, the Location header is correct, according to the requested path. The browser does send another request to the right location, and receive the right response, it's just it doesn't display the html, doesn't change the contents of the page

Comment: do all browsers behave in this way?