# How to redirect from React front-end with Rails routes?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redirect, routes

I am new to React and struggling to redirect after making a post request to my api.

In an erb view, I am using a javascript pack tag to render some React components on a new resource page. I am using a button onClick to send my post request (axios) to `api/v1/resources`. I'd like to redirect to `admin/resources` after the request is sent.

1. I am wondering why redirecting from the `create` action in my `Api::V1::ResourcesController` doesn't work.
2. Can I redirect without setting up react router? If not, how can I set that up? (All of my routes are defined in Rails).

Everything I can find seems to pertain to an *entire* React front-end when I am only using bits of React in a predominantly Rails front-end.

This is my handleSubmit function that gets called onClick:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    let newResourceParams = {
      title: title,
      description: description,
      occurred_on: occurredOn,
      resource_type: resourceType
    }
    Api.postNewResource(newResourceParams)
  }
```

Here is `Api.postNewResource`:

```
postNewResource(data) {
    return AxiosApi.post('/api/v1/resources', data)
      .then(({data}) => data['data'])
      .catch((errors) =>
        console.log(errors)
      )
  }
```

And here is my `create` action in `Api::V1::ResourcesController`:

```
def create
  Resource.create(resource_params)
  redirect_to admin_resources_path
end
```

Any guidance or help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
redirect_to admin_resources_path, format: :json
```

Let me know if any luck with that?

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304073/rails-how-to-set-json-format-for-redirect-to)

P.S. Very well formulated question. ;)